# Removing two asterisks on Bootstrap 4 Yes/No radio buttons for a required question and only having one after the label

Tags: validation, bootstrap-4, radio-button, radio-group, required

I have a form using Bootstrap 4 with a required Yes/No question, but when adding 'required' to each radio box, which is necessary to make sure one of them is selected, they both end up with asterisks, which could be confusing to the visitor. How can I remove the two asterisks from before their labels associated with the radio button? There's an asterisk in front of Yes and another asterisk in front of No. Here's the code I have so far:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="labeltext required">Is this yes or no?</label><br>
      <div class="form-check-inline">
        <label class="question12"><span class="radioQ">Yes</span>
          <input type="radio" name="Q12" value="Yes" id="Q1Yes" required>
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <label class="question12"><span class="radioQ">No</span>
          <input type="radio" name="Q12" value="No" id="Q1No" required>
          <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why not put an * inside the label?

Comment: We need to indicate that one of the radio buttons is selected. They have to select either Yes or No. If we take away 'required' from the input, then we'll lose the validation and forms could end up being submitted without either selected.

Comment: you are right... i am asking why can't we use: `<label class="labeltext">Is this yes or no?*</label>`

Comment: I added 'required' to my original post on the second line (class="labeltext required"), but still need to remove the asterisks from the two radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking way too deeply into this. Here's the solution:

```
    label.question12.required:before {
        display:none;
    }
```